# Can databinding set the actual dp if available, otherwise fallback to resource in Android?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a `TextView` I want to set padding to it. For example it'll be `paddingLeft`. I want to allow some configuration on the padding but at the same time, if padding value is not provided, I want to have a default value. What I currently have looks like this -

```
android:paddingLeft="@{vm.padding == 0 ? context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(vm.defaultPadding) : vm.padding}"
```

`vm.defaultPadding` would look like `R.dimen.default_padding`. This works if the resource of `vm.defaultPadding` is provided within the module. However, when I have the `xml` and `vm` in different modules, it gave me an error that it cant locate the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps trying this snippet for getting the padding from a different module:

```
    public int getPadding(Context context, int padding, @DimenRes int defaultPaddingResId) {
    
        int defaultPadding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(defaultPaddingResId);
        return padding != 0 ? padding : defaultPadding;

}
```

The xml can look like this:

`android:paddingLeft="@{vm.getPadding(context, vm.padding, R.dimen.default_padding)}"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).